# Express $\cos 4x$ in terms of only $\sin 2x$ and hence solve the trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to express $\cos 4x$ in terms of only $\sin 2x$ and hence solve the trigonometric equation with the restriction of $\theta \in (0^{\circ}, 135^{\circ})$

$$\frac{\cos 5 \theta}{\sin \theta} + \frac{\sin 5 \theta}{\cos \theta} = 2.$$

I have come up to this point:

$$\cos 4x = \cos (2x + 2x) = \cos 2x \cos 2x - \sin 2x \sin 2x = (\cos(2x))^2 - (\sin(2x))^2.$$

Now I only need to express $\cos 2x$ in terms of $\sin 2x$, but for all quadrants.  Regarding the trigonometric equation, I have done these steps:

\begin{align}
\frac{\cos(5x)\cos(x) + \sin(5x)\sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=2
&\implies \cos(5x-x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x) \\
&\implies \cos(4x)=\sin(2x).
\end{align}

So I believe that when I express $\cos(4x)$ in terms of $\sin 2x$ I continue with solving the equation.

Comment: $$\sin^2{(2x)}+\cos^2{(2x)}=1$$

Comment: $sin(x) = cos(x)$ if and only if $x = 45°$ or $x = 135°$

Comment: @ZAF $4x \ne 2x$, so your result does not apply.

Comment: $(\cos 2x)^2 = 1 - (\sin 2x)^2$  And that's true for all quadrants.  So you have (if you've done your trig correctly; I did not double check) that $1-2(\sin 2x)^2 = \sin 2x$ which is simply a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange

$$\dfrac{\cos 5 \theta}{\sin \theta} + \dfrac{\sin 5 \theta}{\cos \theta} = 2$$

to get

$$\cos(4\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$$

Then, use $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$

$$1-2\sin^2(2\theta)= \sin(2\theta)$$

$$\sin(2\theta) = -1,  \space \sin(2\theta)=1/2$$

$$\theta = 15^\circ,\space \theta=75^\circ$$

Comment: First case: $2 \theta = \arcsin (-1) = - \dfrac{\pi}{2} $... Shouldn't $\theta$ in that case be $- \dfrac{\pi}{4}.$ ?

Comment: Your $\theta$ is restricted to $\theta \in (0^{\circ}, 135^{\circ})$. So, $-45^\circ$ is excluded

Comment: Now I understand, both solutions are for the second case. Thanks.

Comment: What about $2\theta = 1.5 \pi $?

Comment: You get $135^\circ$, which is outside the domain specified.

Comment: @Quanto You're right! I've missed the exclusion of 135*. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** 
$$\cos 4x = \cos^2 2x - \sin^2 2x = 1-\sin^2 2x - \sin^2 2x = 1-2\sin^2 2x$$

Answer (score 1):

Since Cos4X = Sin 2X ,$$
           Cos 4X = Cos (90 - 2X) $$
            4X = 2nπ $\pm$(90-2X) $$
         Hence \,X = 15 , 75 $$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $$\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ we get
$$\cos(5x)\cos(x)+\sin(5x)\sin(x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and this is
$$\cos(5x-x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(4x)=\sin(2x)$$
$$\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)=\sin(2x)$$